# How do I create a login feature for my iOS app that only allows authorized users (determined by me) and does not include a "register account" feature

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication

The chat portion of my app currently uses firebase; therefore, I realize that the easiest way to create a login feature would probably be through firebase. I want to make it so that I hard code the usernames and passwords into my authentication database and distribute them accordingly so that only users who have received their login info from me can login. Currently, the firebase email/password authentication includes a "register account" feature by default and I do not want users to have the ability to register. Due to my lack of experience, I am unsure how to work around this. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can programmatically [create email/password accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) using the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).  You have no obligation to provide a sign-up form, just a sign-in form for the accounts you create.